# Issues with malloc

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

When allocating memory for the 2-dimensional array using `malloc()`,segmentation fault occurs when the input size(matrix N*N) is more than `5` (i.e., `N>5`).

The below code is working fine for inputs(N) less than `5`.

Could you please help me out in figuring the problem?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    int i,j;
    int **adj;
    //reading size of a N*N matrix
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //dynamically allocating memory for a 2-dimensional array
    adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        adj[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
    }

    //taking input from the file        
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            scanf("%d",&adj[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            printf("%d\t",adj[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If N is constant per-array, it would be better if you realign it to one-dimentional array and calculate element index by simple multiplication by N. Beyond that, it should be `adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*)*n);`

Comment: I hope it just was a bad copy-paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

as you are allocating an array of `int*`, not `int`. Change to:

```
adj = malloc(sizeof(int*)*n); /* Cast unnecessary. */
/* or: adj = malloc(sizeof(*adj)*n); */
```

---

Recommend checking return value of `scanf()` to ensure an `int` was correctly read:

```
if (1 == scanf("%d", &n))
{
}
```

Useful read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: To help the OP understand why, it's because on a 64-bit platform pointers are 64 bits (i.e. 8 bytes) while `int` is 32 bits (i.e. 4 bytes). So calling `malloc` with `sizeof(int)` means that the allocated memory will be _half_ of whats needed.

Comment: Size of integer on a machine depends on the combination of underlying OS and architecture. If OS (plus GCC) is 64 bits on a 64 bit machine, integer as well as a pointer too takes 8 bytes (64 bits)... isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
adj=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int)*n);
```

Replace this with

```
adj = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
```

Because in general `sizeof(int*) != sizeof(int)`

And another tip: initialize your variables!!!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to that what hmjd pointer out, perhaps it may provide few more information.

int p  ->   p is of type int.

int * p ->   p is pointer (*p) type pointing to 'int"

int ** p ->  p is pointer (*p) type pointing to "pointer to int ie: (int *)"

If it is read from left to write, it will be easier to understand.

int ** adj -> you need two pointer dereferences ( **) to reach the value 'int'.

ie: each location in the memory array pointed by 'adj',  should hold the address of another chunk of memory. Hence  you need to provide sizeof(int *), while allocating 'adj'.